# ng-show show error when input is empty

Tags: angularjs

Ok i have :

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="address" class="control-label col-lg-5 col-md-6">                                @Html.Label(@Translator.Translate("STREET_ADDRESS")):
<span ng-show="editUserForm.Address.$error.required" class="required">*</span>
</label>
<div class="col-lg-7 col-md-6">
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address, new {name="Address", @class = "form-control", id = "address", @maxlength = "30", ng_model = "address", @required = "required", ng_pattern = @"/[A-Za-z]+ ?[0-9]+$/" })
</div>
</div>
```

So my idea is when this textbox is empty that show * but for me it not working...Any help?

Comment: What happens if you click in the text box (give it focus) and then click away (blur)?

Comment: for now i able to made iwhen user enter address textbox gets green when is empty textbox is red...but im not able also to show * when its empty

Comment: if it click in textbox and then click away depends of what user enter

Comment: what about <span ng-show="!!address">*</span> ?

Comment: yes...with one ! not double :) tnx

Comment: I'll move this to an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Moved from comments) Change the span to this:

```
<span ng-show="!address">*</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   <span ng-show="editUserForm.Address.$dirty && editUserForm.Address.$error.required" class="required">*</span>
```